# I have a dataset in which i have two columns with time in it but the dat

Tags: python, pandas

```
Unnamed: 0     Created Date             Closed Date            Agency   Agency Name  Complaint Type Descriptor  Location Type   Incident Zip    Address Type    City    Landmark    Status  Borough
2869    2869    10/30/2013 09:14:47 AM  10/30/2013 10:48:51 AM  NYPD    New York City Police Department Illegal Parking Double Parked Blocking Traffic  Street/Sidewalk 11217.0 PLACENAME   BROOKLYN    BARCLAYS CENTER Closed  BROOKLYN
23571   23571   10/25/2013 02:33:54 PM  10/25/2013 03:36:36 PM  NYPD    New York City Police Department Noise - Park    Loud Music/Party    Park/Playground 10000   PLACENAME   NEW YORK    CENTRAL PARK    Closed  MANHATTAN
41625   41625   10/22/2013 09:33:56 PM  10/24/2013 05:37:24 PM  TLC Taxi and Limousine Commission   For Hire Vehicle Complaint  Car Service Company Complaint   Street  11430   PLACENAME   JAMAICA J F K AIRPORT   Closed  QUEENS
44331   44331   10/22/2013 07:25:35 AM  10/25/2013 10:40:35 AM  TLC Taxi and Limousine Commission   Taxi Complaint  Driver Complaint    Street  11430   PLACENAME   JAMAICA J F K AIRPORT   Closed  QUEENS
46913   46913   10/21/2013 05:03:26 PM  10/23/2013 09:59:23 AM  DPR Department of Parks and Recreation  Dead Tree   Dead/Dying Tree Street  11215   PLACENAME   BROOKLYN    BARTEL PRITCHARD SQUARE Closed  BROOKLYN
47459   47459   10/21/2013 02:56:08 PM  10/29/2013 06:17:10 PM  TLC Taxi and Limousine Commission   Taxi Complaint  Driver Complaint    Street  10031   PLACENAME   NEW YORK    CITY COLLEGE    Closed  MANHATTAN
48465   48465   10/21/2013 10:44:10 AM  10/21/2013 11:17:47 AM  NYPD    New York City Police Department Illegal Parking Posted Parking Sign Violation   Street/Sidewalk 11434   PLACENAME   JAMAICA PS 37   Closed  QUEENS
51837   51837   10/20/2013 04:36:12 PM  10/20/2013 06:35:49 PM  NYPD    New York City Police Department Noise - Park    Loud Music/Party    Park/Playground 10031.0 PLACENAME   NEW YORK    JACKIE ROBINSON PARK    Closed  MANHATTAN
51848   51848   10/20/2013 04:26:03 PM  10/20/2013 06:34:47 PM  NYPD    New York City Police Department Noise - Park    Loud Music/Party    Park/Playground 10031.0 PLACENAME   NEW YORK    JACKIE ROBINSON PARK    Closed  MANHATTAN
54089   54089   10/19/2013 03:45:47 PM  10/19/2013 04:10:11 PM  NYPD    New York City Police Department Noise - Park    Loud Music/Party    Park/Playground 10000.0 PLACENAME   NEW YORK    CENTRAL PARK    Closed  MANHATTAN
54343   54343   10/19/2013 01:27:43 PM  10/28/2013 08:42:12 AM  DOT Department of Transportation    Street Condition    Rough, Pitted or Cracked Roads  Street  10003.0 PLACENAME   NEW YORK    UNION SQUARE PARK   Closed  MANHATTAN
55140   55140   10/19/2013 02:02:28 AM  10/19/2013 02:19:55 AM  NYPD    New York City Police Department Noise - Vehicle Car/Truck Music Street/Sidewalk 11368.0 PLACENAME   CORONA  WORLDS FAIR MARINA  Closed  QUEENS
57789   57789   10/18/2013 11:55:44 AM  10/23/2013 02:42:14 PM  TLC Taxi and Limousine Commission   Taxi Complaint  Driver Complaint    Street  11369.0 PLACENAME   EAST ELMHURST   LA GUARDIA AIRPORT  Closed  QUEENS
63119   63119   10/17/2013 06:52:37 AM  10/25/2013 06:49:59 PM  TLC Taxi and Limousine Commission   Taxi Complaint  Driver Complaint    Street  11430.0 PLACENAME   JAMAICA J F K AIRPORT   Closed  QUEENS
66242   66242   10/16/2013 01:56:24 PM  10/22/2013 03:09:11 PM  TLC Taxi and Limousine Commission   Taxi Complaint  Driver Complaint    Street  11369   PLACENAME   EAST ELMHURST   LA GUARDIA AIRPORT  Closed  QUEENS
66758   66758   10/16/2013 11:52:43 AM  10/16/2013 04:35:34 PM  NYPD    New York City Police Department Vending Unlicensed  Park/Playground 10036   PLACENAME   NEW YORK    BRYANT PARK Closed  MANHATTAN
66786   66786   10/16/2013 11:42:23 AM  10/18/2013 04:57:04 PM  TLC Taxi and Limousine Commission   Taxi Complaint  Insurance Information Requested Street  10003   PLACENAME   NEW YORK    BETH ISRAEL MED CENTER  Closed  MANHATTAN
66809   66809   10/16/2013 11:36:54 AM  10/16/2013 12:34:23 PM  NYPD    New York City Police Department Traffic Congestion/Gridlock Street/Sidewalk 11430   PLACENAME   JAMAICA J F K AIRPORT   Closed  QUEENS
67465   67465   10/16/2013 09:14:35 AM  10/16/2013 12:43:06 PM  NYPD    New York City Police Department Traffic Drag Racing Street/Sidewalk 11367   PLACENAME   FLUSHING    QUEENS COLLEGE  Closed  QUEENS
72424   72424   10/15/2013 12:22:00 AM  10/21/2013 12:16:15 PM  TLC Taxi and Limousine Commission   Taxi Complaint  Driver Complaint    Street  11217   PLACENAME   BROOKLYN    BARCLAYS CENTER Closed  BROOKLYN
75531   75531   10/14/2013 10:59:20 AM  10/14/2013 03:09:51 PM  NYPD    New York City Police Department Vending In Prohibited Area  Park/Playground 10000   PLACENAME   NEW YORK    CENTRAL PARK    Closed  MANHATTAN
77918   77918   10/13/2013 03:16:03 PM  10/13/2013 03:25:45 PM  NYPD    New York City Police Department Noise - Park    Loud Music/Party    Park/Playground 10000   PLACENAME   NEW YORK    CENTRAL PARK    Closed  MANHATTAN
78048   78048   10/13/2013 01:06:02 PM  10/21/2013 10:20:21 AM  TLC Taxi and Limousine Commission   Taxi Complaint  Driver Complaint    Street  11369   PLACENAME   EAST ELMHURST   LA GUARDIA AIRPORT  Closed  QUEENS
78352   78352   10/13/2013 05:14:33 AM  10/16/2013 01:42:42 PM  TLC Taxi and Limousine Commission   For Hire Vehicle Complaint  Car Service Company Complaint   Street  11217   PLACENAME   BROOKLYN    BARCLAYS CENTER Closed  BROOKLYN
78383   78383   10/13/2013 03:50:02 AM  10/13/2013 05:03:13 AM  NYPD    New York City Police Department Noise - Vehicle Car/Truck Music Street/Sidewalk 11368   PLACENAME   CORONA  WORLDS FAIR MARINA  Closed  QUEENS
79078   79078   10/12/2013 09:53:17 PM  10/13/2013 02:52:07 AM  NYPD    New York City Police Department Noise - Park    Loud Music/Party    Park/Playground 10011   PLACENAME   NEW YORK    WASHINGTON SQUARE PARK  Closed  MANHATTAN
84489   84489   10/10/2013 07:16:16 PM  10/10/2013 10:29:16 PM  NYPD    New York City Police Department Noise - Park    Loud Music/Party    Park/Playground 11215   PLACENAME   BROOKLYN    PROSPECT PARK   Closed  BROOKLYN
84518   84518   10/10/2013 07:02:29 PM  10/10/2013 10:29:16 PM  NYPD    New York City Police Department Noise - Park    Loud Music/Party    Park/Playground 11215   PLACENAME   BROOKLYN    PROSPECT PARK   Closed  BROOKLYN
84688   84688   10/10/2013 05:39:19 PM  10/10/2013 10:29:17 PM  NYPD    New York City Police Department Noise - Park    Loud Music/Party    Park/Playground 11215   PLACENAME   BROOKLYN    PROSPECT PARK   Closed  BROOKLYN
84695   84695   10/10/2013 05:37:04 PM  10/10/2013 10:30:19 PM  NYPD    New York City Police Department Noise - Park    Loud Music/Party    Park/Playground 11215   PLACENAME   BROOKLYN    PROSPECT PARK   Closed  BROOKLYN
88812   88812   10/09/2013 09:17:15 PM  10/23/2013 02:15:21 PM  TLC Taxi and Limousine Commission   Taxi Complaint  Driver Complaint    Street  11430   PLACENAME   JAMAICA J F K AIRPORT   Closed  QUEENS
89205   89205   10/09/2013 06:01:48 PM  10/09/2013 09:04:26 PM  NYPD    New York City Police Department Vending Unlicensed  Park/Playground 10000   PLACENAME   NEW YORK    CENTRAL PARK    Closed  MANHATTAN
89382   89382   10/09/2013 04:53:01 PM  10/18/2013 08:35:02 AM  DOT Department of Transportation    Public Toilet   Damaged Door    Sidewalk    11238   PLACENAME   BROOKLYN    GRAND ARMY PLAZA    Closed  BROOKLYN
89734   89734   10/09/2013 03:13:23 PM  10/09/2013 05:10:45 PM  NYPD    New York City Police Department Noise - Park    Loud Music/Party    Park/Playground 10036   PLACENAME   NEW YORK    BRYANT PARK Closed  MANHATTAN
93990   93990   10/08/2013 06:14:15 PM  10/09/2013 04:00:59 PM  TLC Taxi and Limousine Commission   Taxi Complaint  Driver Complaint    Street  10003   PLACENAME   NEW YORK    BETH ISRAEL MED CENTER  Closed  MANHATTAN
99407   99407   10/07/2013 03:56:11 PM  10/08/2013 07:04:14 AM  DPR Department of Parks and Recreation  Overgrown Tree/Branches Traffic Sign or Signal Blocked  Street  11430.0 PLACENAME   JAMAICA J F K AIRPORT   Closed  QUEENS
99847   99847   10/07/2013 02:33:21 PM  10/09/2013 02:36:42 PM  TLC Taxi and Limousine Commission   Taxi Complaint  Driver Complaint    Street  10036.0 PLACENAME   NEW YORK    PORT AUTH 42 STREET Closed  MANHATTAN
100073  100073  10/07/2013 01:36:02 PM  10/09/2013 09:56:55 AM  TLC Taxi and Limousine Commission   Taxi Complaint  Driver Complaint    Street  10024.0 PLACENAME   NEW YORK    MUSEUM NATURAL HIST Closed  MANHATTAN
101013  101013  10/07/2013 10:05:18 AM  10/09/2013 03:36:23 PM  TLC Taxi and Limousine Commission   Taxi Complaint  Driver Complaint    Street  10017.0 PLACENAME   NEW YORK    GRAND CENTRAL TERM  Closed  MANHATTAN
104020  104020  10/06/2013 02:58:47 PM  10/07/2013 12:11:16 PM  TLC Taxi and Limousine Commission   For Hire Vehicle Complaint  Car Service Company Complaint   Street  11430.0 PLACENAME   JAMAICA JFK Closed  QUEENS
106118  106118  10/05/2013 03:24:47 PM  10/05/2013 04:20:34 PM  NYPD    New York City Police Department Noise - Park    Loud Music/Party    Park/Playground 10000.0 PLACENAME   NEW YORK    CENTRAL PARK    Closed  MANHATTAN
106499  106499  10/05/2013 11:52:13 AM  10/07/2013 08:00:28 AM  DOT Department of Transportation    Public Toilet   Dirty/Graffiti  Sidewalk    11369.0 PLACENAME   EAST ELMHURST   LA GUARDIA AIRPORT  Closed  QUEENS
```

this is how my data looks like.
What I want to do here is to extract date from created date and closed date I have tried .extract method but I am new to this so, it didn't work. I want to calculate housrs from created date and closed which i can do like this:

```py
pd.Timedelta(task3['Closed Date'] - task3['Created Date']).seconds / 60.0
```

In the end I want the output
Find average
completion time in hours for top-10 most frequent complaints. Also calculate how many data points
you have for each complaint types. Do this analysis only for closed complaints.
The sample output I want is as follows:

```
                         mean                   count
complaint Type           closing_time_hours     closing_time_hours
Blocked Driveway         3.00                   4581
DOF Literature Request   30.16                  5481
General Construction     66.38                  798
Heating                  54.88                  6704
Illegal Parking          3.08                   3336
Nonconst                 65                     100 
Paint-Plaster            49                     3281 
Plumbing                 65                     666   
Strret Condition         81                     2610    
Street Light Condition   90                     4207
```

these mean and count values are randomly generated
The sample output can be produced by groupby function once the hours are extracted from the data.
dictionary format

```
{'Unnamed: 0': {2869: 2869,
  23571: 23571,
  41625: 41625,
  44331: 44331,
  46913: 46913,
  47459: 47459,
  48465: 48465,
  51837: 51837,
  51848: 51848,
  54089: 54089,
  54343: 54343,
  55140: 55140,
  57789: 57789,
  63119: 63119,
  66242: 66242,
  66758: 66758,
  66786: 66786,
  66809: 66809,
  67465: 67465,
  72424: 72424,
  75531: 75531,
  77918: 77918,
  78048: 78048,
  78352: 78352,
  78383: 78383,
  79078: 79078,
  84489: 84489,
  84518: 84518,
  84688: 84688,
  84695: 84695,
  88812: 88812,
  89205: 89205,
  89382: 89382,
  89734: 89734,
  93990: 93990,
  99407: 99407,
  99847: 99847,
  100073: 100073,
  101013: 101013,
  104020: 104020,
  106118: 106118,
  106499: 106499},
 'Created Date': {2869: '10/30/2013 09:14:47 AM',
  23571: '10/25/2013 02:33:54 PM',
  41625: '10/22/2013 09:33:56 PM',
  44331: '10/22/2013 07:25:35 AM',
  46913: '10/21/2013 05:03:26 PM',
  47459: '10/21/2013 02:56:08 PM',
  48465: '10/21/2013 10:44:10 AM',
  51837: '10/20/2013 04:36:12 PM',
  51848: '10/20/2013 04:26:03 PM',
  54089: '10/19/2013 03:45:47 PM',
  54343: '10/19/2013 01:27:43 PM',
  55140: '10/19/2013 02:02:28 AM',
  57789: '10/18/2013 11:55:44 AM',
  63119: '10/17/2013 06:52:37 AM',
  66242: '10/16/2013 01:56:24 PM',
  66758: '10/16/2013 11:52:43 AM',
  66786: '10/16/2013 11:42:23 AM',
  66809: '10/16/2013 11:36:54 AM',
  67465: '10/16/2013 09:14:35 AM',
  72424: '10/15/2013 12:22:00 AM',
  75531: '10/14/2013 10:59:20 AM',
  77918: '10/13/2013 03:16:03 PM',
  78048: '10/13/2013 01:06:02 PM',
  78352: '10/13/2013 05:14:33 AM',
  78383: '10/13/2013 03:50:02 AM',
  79078: '10/12/2013 09:53:17 PM',
  84489: '10/10/2013 07:16:16 PM',
  84518: '10/10/2013 07:02:29 PM',
  84688: '10/10/2013 05:39:19 PM',
  84695: '10/10/2013 05:37:04 PM',
  88812: '10/09/2013 09:17:15 PM',
  89205: '10/09/2013 06:01:48 PM',
  89382: '10/09/2013 04:53:01 PM',
  89734: '10/09/2013 03:13:23 PM',
  93990: '10/08/2013 06:14:15 PM',
  99407: '10/07/2013 03:56:11 PM',
  99847: '10/07/2013 02:33:21 PM',
  100073: '10/07/2013 01:36:02 PM',
  101013: '10/07/2013 10:05:18 AM',
  104020: '10/06/2013 02:58:47 PM',
  106118: '10/05/2013 03:24:47 PM',
  106499: '10/05/2013 11:52:13 AM'},
 'Closed Date': {2869: '10/30/2013 10:48:51 AM',
  23571: '10/25/2013 03:36:36 PM',
  41625: '10/24/2013 05:37:24 PM',
  44331: '10/25/2013 10:40:35 AM',
  46913: '10/23/2013 09:59:23 AM',
  47459: '10/29/2013 06:17:10 PM',
  48465: '10/21/2013 11:17:47 AM',
  51837: '10/20/2013 06:35:49 PM',
  51848: '10/20/2013 06:34:47 PM',
  54089: '10/19/2013 04:10:11 PM',
  54343: '10/28/2013 08:42:12 AM',
  55140: '10/19/2013 02:19:55 AM',
  57789: '10/23/2013 02:42:14 PM',
  63119: '10/25/2013 06:49:59 PM',
  66242: '10/22/2013 03:09:11 PM',
  66758: '10/16/2013 04:35:34 PM',
  66786: '10/18/2013 04:57:04 PM',
  66809: '10/16/2013 12:34:23 PM',
  67465: '10/16/2013 12:43:06 PM',
  72424: '10/21/2013 12:16:15 PM',
  75531: '10/14/2013 03:09:51 PM',
  77918: '10/13/2013 03:25:45 PM',
  78048: '10/21/2013 10:20:21 AM',
  78352: '10/16/2013 01:42:42 PM',
  78383: '10/13/2013 05:03:13 AM',
  79078: '10/13/2013 02:52:07 AM',
  84489: '10/10/2013 10:29:16 PM',
  84518: '10/10/2013 10:29:16 PM',
  84688: '10/10/2013 10:29:17 PM',
  84695: '10/10/2013 10:30:19 PM',
  88812: '10/23/2013 02:15:21 PM',
  89205: '10/09/2013 09:04:26 PM',
  89382: '10/18/2013 08:35:02 AM',
  89734: '10/09/2013 05:10:45 PM',
  93990: '10/09/2013 04:00:59 PM',
  99407: '10/08/2013 07:04:14 AM',
  99847: '10/09/2013 02:36:42 PM',
  100073: '10/09/2013 09:56:55 AM',
  101013: '10/09/2013 03:36:23 PM',
  104020: '10/07/2013 12:11:16 PM',
  106118: '10/05/2013 04:20:34 PM',
  106499: '10/07/2013 08:00:28 AM'},
 'Agency': {2869: 'NYPD',
  23571: 'NYPD',
  41625: 'TLC',
  44331: 'TLC',
  46913: 'DPR',
  47459: 'TLC',
  48465: 'NYPD',
  51837: 'NYPD',
  51848: 'NYPD',
  54089: 'NYPD',
  54343: 'DOT',
  55140: 'NYPD',
  57789: 'TLC',
  63119: 'TLC',
  66242: 'TLC',
  66758: 'NYPD',
  66786: 'TLC',
  66809: 'NYPD',
  67465: 'NYPD',
  72424: 'TLC',
  75531: 'NYPD',
  77918: 'NYPD',
  78048: 'TLC',
  78352: 'TLC',
  78383: 'NYPD',
  79078: 'NYPD',
  84489: 'NYPD',
  84518: 'NYPD',
  84688: 'NYPD',
  84695: 'NYPD',
  88812: 'TLC',
  89205: 'NYPD',
  89382: 'DOT',
  89734: 'NYPD',
  93990: 'TLC',
  99407: 'DPR',
  99847: 'TLC',
  100073: 'TLC',
  101013: 'TLC',
  104020: 'TLC',
  106118: 'NYPD',
  106499: 'DOT'},
 'Agency Name': {2869: 'New York City Police Department',
  23571: 'New York City Police Department',
  41625: 'Taxi and Limousine Commission',
  44331: 'Taxi and Limousine Commission',
  46913: 'Department of Parks and Recreation',
  47459: 'Taxi and Limousine Commission',
  48465: 'New York City Police Department',
  51837: 'New York City Police Department',
  51848: 'New York City Police Department',
  54089: 'New York City Police Department',
  54343: 'Department of Transportation',
  55140: 'New York City Police Department',
  57789: 'Taxi and Limousine Commission',
  63119: 'Taxi and Limousine Commission',
  66242: 'Taxi and Limousine Commission',
  66758: 'New York City Police Department',
  66786: 'Taxi and Limousine Commission',
  66809: 'New York City Police Department',
  67465: 'New York City Police Department',
  72424: 'Taxi and Limousine Commission',
  75531: 'New York City Police Department',
  77918: 'New York City Police Department',
  78048: 'Taxi and Limousine Commission',
  78352: 'Taxi and Limousine Commission',
  78383: 'New York City Police Department',
  79078: 'New York City Police Department',
  84489: 'New York City Police Department',
  84518: 'New York City Police Department',
  84688: 'New York City Police Department',
  84695: 'New York City Police Department',
  88812: 'Taxi and Limousine Commission',
  89205: 'New York City Police Department',
  89382: 'Department of Transportation',
  89734: 'New York City Police Department',
  93990: 'Taxi and Limousine Commission',
  99407: 'Department of Parks and Recreation',
  99847: 'Taxi and Limousine Commission',
  100073: 'Taxi and Limousine Commission',
  101013: 'Taxi and Limousine Commission',
  104020: 'Taxi and Limousine Commission',
  106118: 'New York City Police Department',
  106499: 'Department of Transportation'},
 'Complaint Type': {2869: 'Illegal Parking',
  23571: 'Noise - Park',
  41625: 'For Hire Vehicle Complaint',
  44331: 'Taxi Complaint',
  46913: 'Dead Tree',
  47459: 'Taxi Complaint',
  48465: 'Illegal Parking',
  51837: 'Noise - Park',
  51848: 'Noise - Park',
  54089: 'Noise - Park',
  54343: 'Street Condition',
  55140: 'Noise - Vehicle',
  57789: 'Taxi Complaint',
  63119: 'Taxi Complaint',
  66242: 'Taxi Complaint',
  66758: 'Vending',
  66786: 'Taxi Complaint',
  66809: 'Traffic',
  67465: 'Traffic',
  72424: 'Taxi Complaint',
  75531: 'Vending',
  77918: 'Noise - Park',
  78048: 'Taxi Complaint',
  78352: 'For Hire Vehicle Complaint',
  78383: 'Noise - Vehicle',
  79078: 'Noise - Park',
  84489: 'Noise - Park',
  84518: 'Noise - Park',
  84688: 'Noise - Park',
  84695: 'Noise - Park',
  88812: 'Taxi Complaint',
  89205: 'Vending',
  89382: 'Public Toilet',
  89734: 'Noise - Park',
  93990: 'Taxi Complaint',
  99407: 'Overgrown Tree/Branches',
  99847: 'Taxi Complaint',
  100073: 'Taxi Complaint',
  101013: 'Taxi Complaint',
  104020: 'For Hire Vehicle Complaint',
  106118: 'Noise - Park',
  106499: 'Public Toilet'},
 'Descriptor': {2869: 'Double Parked Blocking Traffic',
  23571: 'Loud Music/Party',
  41625: 'Car Service Company Complaint',
  44331: 'Driver Complaint',
  46913: 'Dead/Dying Tree',
  47459: 'Driver Complaint',
  48465: 'Posted Parking Sign Violation',
  51837: 'Loud Music/Party',
  51848: 'Loud Music/Party',
  54089: 'Loud Music/Party',
  54343: 'Rough, Pitted or Cracked Roads',
  55140: 'Car/Truck Music',
  57789: 'Driver Complaint',
  63119: 'Driver Complaint',
  66242: 'Driver Complaint',
  66758: 'Unlicensed',
  66786: 'Insurance Information Requested',
  66809: 'Congestion/Gridlock',
  67465: 'Drag Racing',
  72424: 'Driver Complaint',
  75531: 'In Prohibited Area',
  77918: 'Loud Music/Party',
  78048: 'Driver Complaint',
  78352: 'Car Service Company Complaint',
  78383: 'Car/Truck Music',
  79078: 'Loud Music/Party',
  84489: 'Loud Music/Party',
  84518: 'Loud Music/Party',
  84688: 'Loud Music/Party',
  84695: 'Loud Music/Party',
  88812: 'Driver Complaint',
  89205: 'Unlicensed',
  89382: 'Damaged Door',
  89734: 'Loud Music/Party',
  93990: 'Driver Complaint',
  99407: 'Traffic Sign or Signal Blocked',
  99847: 'Driver Complaint',
  100073: 'Driver Complaint',
  101013: 'Driver Complaint',
  104020: 'Car Service Company Complaint',
  106118: 'Loud Music/Party',
  106499: 'Dirty/Graffiti'},
 'Location Type': {2869: 'Street/Sidewalk',
  23571: 'Park/Playground',
  41625: 'Street',
  44331: 'Street',
  46913: 'Street',
  47459: 'Street',
  48465: 'Street/Sidewalk',
  51837: 'Park/Playground',
  51848: 'Park/Playground',
  54089: 'Park/Playground',
  54343: 'Street',
  55140: 'Street/Sidewalk',
  57789: 'Street',
  63119: 'Street',
  66242: 'Street',
  66758: 'Park/Playground',
  66786: 'Street',
  66809: 'Street/Sidewalk',
  67465: 'Street/Sidewalk',
  72424: 'Street',
  75531: 'Park/Playground',
  77918: 'Park/Playground',
  78048: 'Street',
  78352: 'Street',
  78383: 'Street/Sidewalk',
  79078: 'Park/Playground',
  84489: 'Park/Playground',
  84518: 'Park/Playground',
  84688: 'Park/Playground',
  84695: 'Park/Playground',
  88812: 'Street',
  89205: 'Park/Playground',
  89382: 'Sidewalk',
  89734: 'Park/Playground',
  93990: 'Street',
  99407: 'Street',
  99847: 'Street',
  100073: 'Street',
  101013: 'Street',
  104020: 'Street',
  106118: 'Park/Playground',
  106499: 'Sidewalk'},
 'Incident Zip': {2869: '11217.0',
  23571: '10000',
  41625: '11430',
  44331: '11430',
  46913: '11215',
  47459: '10031',
  48465: '11434',
  51837: '10031.0',
  51848: '10031.0',
  54089: '10000.0',
  54343: '10003.0',
  55140: '11368.0',
  57789: '11369.0',
  63119: '11430.0',
  66242: '11369',
  66758: '10036',
  66786: '10003',
  66809: '11430',
  67465: '11367',
  72424: '11217',
  75531: '10000',
  77918: '10000',
  78048: '11369',
  78352: '11217',
  78383: '11368',
  79078: '10011',
  84489: '11215',
  84518: '11215',
  84688: '11215',
  84695: '11215',
  88812: '11430',
  89205: '10000',
  89382: '11238',
  89734: '10036',
  93990: '10003',
  99407: '11430.0',
  99847: '10036.0',
  100073: '10024.0',
  101013: '10017.0',
  104020: '11430.0',
  106118: '10000.0',
  106499: '11369.0'},
 'Address Type': {2869: 'PLACENAME',
  23571: 'PLACENAME',
  41625: 'PLACENAME',
  44331: 'PLACENAME',
  46913: 'PLACENAME',
  47459: 'PLACENAME',
  48465: 'PLACENAME',
  51837: 'PLACENAME',
  51848: 'PLACENAME',
  54089: 'PLACENAME',
  54343: 'PLACENAME',
  55140: 'PLACENAME',
  57789: 'PLACENAME',
  63119: 'PLACENAME',
  66242: 'PLACENAME',
  66758: 'PLACENAME',
  66786: 'PLACENAME',
  66809: 'PLACENAME',
  67465: 'PLACENAME',
  72424: 'PLACENAME',
  75531: 'PLACENAME',
  77918: 'PLACENAME',
  78048: 'PLACENAME',
  78352: 'PLACENAME',
  78383: 'PLACENAME',
  79078: 'PLACENAME',
  84489: 'PLACENAME',
  84518: 'PLACENAME',
  84688: 'PLACENAME',
  84695: 'PLACENAME',
  88812: 'PLACENAME',
  89205: 'PLACENAME',
  89382: 'PLACENAME',
  89734: 'PLACENAME',
  93990: 'PLACENAME',
  99407: 'PLACENAME',
  99847: 'PLACENAME',
  100073: 'PLACENAME',
  101013: 'PLACENAME',
  104020: 'PLACENAME',
  106118: 'PLACENAME',
  106499: 'PLACENAME'},
 'City': {2869: 'BROOKLYN',
  23571: 'NEW YORK',
  41625: 'JAMAICA',
  44331: 'JAMAICA',
  46913: 'BROOKLYN',
  47459: 'NEW YORK',
  48465: 'JAMAICA',
  51837: 'NEW YORK',
  51848: 'NEW YORK',
  54089: 'NEW YORK',
  54343: 'NEW YORK',
  55140: 'CORONA',
  57789: 'EAST ELMHURST',
  63119: 'JAMAICA',
  66242: 'EAST ELMHURST',
  66758: 'NEW YORK',
  66786: 'NEW YORK',
  66809: 'JAMAICA',
  67465: 'FLUSHING',
  72424: 'BROOKLYN',
  75531: 'NEW YORK',
  77918: 'NEW YORK',
  78048: 'EAST ELMHURST',
  78352: 'BROOKLYN',
  78383: 'CORONA',
  79078: 'NEW YORK',
  84489: 'BROOKLYN',
  84518: 'BROOKLYN',
  84688: 'BROOKLYN',
  84695: 'BROOKLYN',
  88812: 'JAMAICA',
  89205: 'NEW YORK',
  89382: 'BROOKLYN',
  89734: 'NEW YORK',
  93990: 'NEW YORK',
  99407: 'JAMAICA',
  99847: 'NEW YORK',
  100073: 'NEW YORK',
  101013: 'NEW YORK',
  104020: 'JAMAICA',
  106118: 'NEW YORK',
  106499: 'EAST ELMHURST'},
 'Landmark': {2869: 'BARCLAYS CENTER',
  23571: 'CENTRAL PARK',
  41625: 'J F K AIRPORT',
  44331: 'J F K AIRPORT',
  46913: 'BARTEL PRITCHARD SQUARE',
  47459: 'CITY COLLEGE',
  48465: 'PS 37',
  51837: 'JACKIE ROBINSON PARK',
  51848: 'JACKIE ROBINSON PARK',
  54089: 'CENTRAL PARK',
  54343: 'UNION SQUARE PARK',
  55140: 'WORLDS FAIR MARINA',
  57789: 'LA GUARDIA AIRPORT',
  63119: 'J F K AIRPORT',
  66242: 'LA GUARDIA AIRPORT',
  66758: 'BRYANT PARK',
  66786: 'BETH ISRAEL MED CENTER',
  66809: 'J F K AIRPORT',
  67465: 'QUEENS COLLEGE',
  72424: 'BARCLAYS CENTER',
  75531: 'CENTRAL PARK',
  77918: 'CENTRAL PARK',
  78048: 'LA GUARDIA AIRPORT',
  78352: 'BARCLAYS CENTER',
  78383: 'WORLDS FAIR MARINA',
  79078: 'WASHINGTON SQUARE PARK',
  84489: 'PROSPECT PARK',
  84518: 'PROSPECT PARK',
  84688: 'PROSPECT PARK',
  84695: 'PROSPECT PARK',
  88812: 'J F K AIRPORT',
  89205: 'CENTRAL PARK',
  89382: 'GRAND ARMY PLAZA',
  89734: 'BRYANT PARK',
  93990: 'BETH ISRAEL MED CENTER',
  99407: 'J F K AIRPORT',
  99847: 'PORT AUTH 42 STREET',
  100073: 'MUSEUM NATURAL HIST',
  101013: 'GRAND CENTRAL TERM',
  104020: 'JFK',
  106118: 'CENTRAL PARK',
  106499: 'LA GUARDIA AIRPORT'},
 'Status': {2869: 'Closed',
  23571: 'Closed',
  41625: 'Closed',
  44331: 'Closed',
  46913: 'Closed',
  47459: 'Closed',
  48465: 'Closed',
  51837: 'Closed',
  51848: 'Closed',
  54089: 'Closed',
  54343: 'Closed',
  55140: 'Closed',
  57789: 'Closed',
  63119: 'Closed',
  66242: 'Closed',
  66758: 'Closed',
  66786: 'Closed',
  66809: 'Closed',
  67465: 'Closed',
  72424: 'Closed',
  75531: 'Closed',
  77918: 'Closed',
  78048: 'Closed',
  78352: 'Closed',
  78383: 'Closed',
  79078: 'Closed',
  84489: 'Closed',
  84518: 'Closed',
  84688: 'Closed',
  84695: 'Closed',
  88812: 'Closed',
  89205: 'Closed',
  89382: 'Closed',
  89734: 'Closed',
  93990: 'Closed',
  99407: 'Closed',
  99847: 'Closed',
  100073: 'Closed',
  101013: 'Closed',
  104020: 'Closed',
  106118: 'Closed',
  106499: 'Closed'},
 'Borough': {2869: 'BROOKLYN',
  23571: 'MANHATTAN',
  41625: 'QUEENS',
  44331: 'QUEENS',
  46913: 'BROOKLYN',
  47459: 'MANHATTAN',
  48465: 'QUEENS',
  51837: 'MANHATTAN',
  51848: 'MANHATTAN',
  54089: 'MANHATTAN',
  54343: 'MANHATTAN',
  55140: 'QUEENS',
  57789: 'QUEENS',
  63119: 'QUEENS',
  66242: 'QUEENS',
  66758: 'MANHATTAN',
  66786: 'MANHATTAN',
  66809: 'QUEENS',
  67465: 'QUEENS',
  72424: 'BROOKLYN',
  75531: 'MANHATTAN',
  77918: 'MANHATTAN',
  78048: 'QUEENS',
  78352: 'BROOKLYN',
  78383: 'QUEENS',
  79078: 'MANHATTAN',
  84489: 'BROOKLYN',
  84518: 'BROOKLYN',
  84688: 'BROOKLYN',
  84695: 'BROOKLYN',
  88812: 'QUEENS',
  89205: 'MANHATTAN',
  89382: 'BROOKLYN',
  89734: 'MANHATTAN',
  93990: 'MANHATTAN',
  99407: 'QUEENS',
  99847: 'MANHATTAN',
  100073: 'MANHATTAN',
  101013: 'MANHATTAN',
  104020: 'QUEENS',
  106118: 'MANHATTAN',
  106499: 'QUEENS'}}
```

Comment: Can you change the way you post your data to be reproducible? Include in your answer the output of the code ```df.to_dict()``` please. Or if your dataframe is called task3, do ```task3.to_dict()```.

Comment: Ok i Have added my data in dictionary format

Comment: @HussnainAmjad are all of those columns necessary to ask this question? Are all of the rows? You should trim this example down the bare minimum columns and rows required to demonstrate your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first start by converting your date columns to datetime type using `pd.to_datetime()`:

```
for c in ['Created Date', 'Closed Date']:
    df[c] = pd.to_datetime(df[c])
    #df[c+'_date'] = df[c].dt.date # to extract the date (for created + closed)
    #df[c+'_time'] = df[c].dt.time # to extract the time (for created + closed)
```

Then you can calculate the difference in time between the two as a new column (as hours) `.astype('timedelta64[h]')`, and then calculate a grouped mean:

```
df['difference in time'] = (df['Closed Date'] - df['Created Date']).astype('timedelta64[h]')
print(df.groupby('Complaint Type').agg({'difference in time':'mean'}))
```

returns:

```
                            difference in time
Complaint Type                                
Dead Tree                            40.000000
For Hire Vehicle Complaint           48.333333
Illegal Parking                       0.500000
Noise - Park                          1.916667
Noise - Vehicle                       0.500000
Overgrown Tree/Branches              15.000000
Public Toilet                       125.500000
Street Condition                    211.000000
Taxi Complaint                      125.461538
Traffic                               1.500000
Vending                               3.666667
```

Comment: how to convert these seconds to hours

Comment: also (df['Closed Date'] - df['Created Date]) it has to be like this i mistyped that

Comment: I have updated the equation to it's right format, and also given the result in hours by chaining ```.astype('timedelta64[h]')``` when we calculate the difference in the time columns.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70452998/i-have-a-question-related-to-pandas-and-kaggle-dataset       please help me with this too